# How can I get the count of rows that equal a certain value while using groupby with Sequelize and SQLite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a table that has `email, name, order_number, review`. All these fields are `text`. I am grouping the results by `email`, and counting how many have an `order_number`.

The value for the `review` field is either `'Live'`, `'Failed'` or `null`. **I would like to count how many times each of these values occurs per email address** and return the count in a new column (`review_live_count`, `review_failed_count` and `review_null_count`).

Here is my current code:

```
let users = await db.reservations.findAll({
    attributes: ['email', 'name',[db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.col('order_number')), 'orders']], group: ["email"],
    raw:true
  });
```

I am using Node, Sequelize and SQLite. `Sequelize` and `sequelize` are both being exposed through the `db` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using sequelize literal

```
let users = await db.reservations.findAll({
attributes: [
  'email', 
  'name',
  [db.sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.col('order_number')), 'orders'],
  [db.sequelize.literal(`COUNT (distinct "id") FILTER ( WHERE "review" = 'Live' )` ), 'review_live_count'],
  [db.sequelize.literal(`COUNT (distinct "id") FILTER ( WHERE "review" = 'Failed' )` ), 'review_failed_count'],
  [db.sequelize.literal(`COUNT (distinct "id") FILTER ( WHERE "review" is null )` ), 'review_null_count'],
],
group: ["email"],
raw:true
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! But this is only giving me `1` or `0` for each field its not giving me the actual count.

Comment: I just edited distinct email to id. Hope there is column id.